# Create a 3 day HR slope column based on date column in R

Tags: r

Data frame looks like this:

```
DATE        Athlete    HR
2020/07/31  Athlete 1   56  
2020/07/30  Athlete 1   58  
2020/07/29  Athlete 1   64  
2020/07/28  Athlete 1   36  
2020/07/27  Athlete 1   57  
2020/07/26  Athlete 1   66
2020/07/25  Athlete 1   69
```

Have looked into `rollapplyr()` and `slope()` but unsure on how to use these functions in order to get a 3 day slope for HR data column using the dates column?

Was thinking that maybe I would have to create a function and use `slope()` within the function in order to calculate the 3 day but unsure how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: From which package is `slope` function from and do you have entry for all dates in `DATE` column or there are some missing dates.

Comment: Using slope from the ncar package where a (x,y) input is used as arguments to calculate the slope with linear regression log. And yes there is a date entry for each day of the calendar year with no missing Date entries. Trying to achieve the same output that excel has with its slope function.